# How to continuously get updates for AudioQueue without a timer

Tags: objective-c, audioqueue

I know you can use the AudioQueueGetCurrentTime method to get the current time. Is there a callback or something that continuously gets called to update your timeline? Or do you just have to create a timer to continuously call AudioQueueGetCurrentTime?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember any other way than timer, but I guess it is possible to implement periodic notifications without timer since you manually enqueue buffers and you know bitrate, etc...

As a side note: why not give a try to AVFoundation (available since iOS 4), it's all implemented there and until you have standard formats playback or you have to support iOS 3.x you don't really have to deal with AudioQueue horror.